# How can I default behat output to use ansi colors

Tags: bdd, behat

I'm using behat2.4.5 on OSX 10.8.3, and behat is not automatically detecting ANSI / Color output compatibility.

I'm forced to run the statement as

```
bin/behat --ansi
```

Is there a way to make this the default in behat.yml, or some other method?

Comment: This no longer exists in Behat 3.1: it is now called --colors instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, on obvious solution that I missed was using an alias:

```
alias behat="bin/behat --ansi"
```

But I wonder if there is a cross platform option available.

Answer (score -2):

Change in FormatProcessor.php:

```
// --[no-]ansi
        ->addOption('--ansi', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
```

to

```
// --[no-]ansi
        ->addOption('--ansi', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
```

Comment: There are always better solutions than changing vendor code (unless you work with some legacy awfulness).